# automatic return type deduction c#

Tags: c#, return-type

In C++14 you can have automatic return type deduction, which speeds up refactoring quite a bit. I'd like to use the same in C# but cannot seem to find it. Maybe there is something by default deduced and I don't need to explicitly ask for it.

So: is there a way in C# to not define the type of the function I'm defining but instead have it automatically deduced by the compiler?

Comment: For a method definition, no, that does not exit. You must explicitly specify the return type.

Comment: Other than generics, no.

Comment: No, there is no type inference for the return type of named functions in C#. Lucky for you the tooling for C# is a lot better than the tooling for C++ refactoring - so renaming a method is easy.

Comment: Benjamin, could you instead make your comment an answer? I think your answer here is much clearer than the discussion going on in the other question (which imho is more asking how to get this inference working, not if it's a C# feature (and it didn't show up when I was searching for it, maybe just because I missed the 'inference' keyword)). And I'll mark it as such.

Comment: This question asks about the C# alternative of C++'s `auto foo() {return 42;}` which infers int from 42, the marked duplicate asks about a completely different thing. In C# it would be something like `var foo() {return 42;}` A syntax like this would be very useful when writing wrappers around existing classes.